# Selenium: How to click on href link when it wont have absolute path

Tags: selenium

I am trying to identify a link in the CQ5 webpage and click on it.

Below is the html code:

```
<a href="/siteadmin" title="Websites"> 
 <div class="icon siteadmin"> 
<div class="title">Websites</div> 
 <div class="description">Create and manage multiple websites.
 </div> 
</div> 
</a>
```

The below are method i tried to find the information and click on it.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Websites")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/siteadmin']")).click();
```

Getting following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (528, 174). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="resourcebox">...</div>`
>     (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 39 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
>   System info: host: 'pilapwin7020', ip: '10.116.252.187', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b), userDataDir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir44444_30971}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=52.0.2743.116, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: 5116ba44126c39293ac466aed3d6608a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click in this case as :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href = '/siteadmin'][title = 'Websites']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the attr contains the string, because it returns the fullpath even if in the HTML shows only `/siteadmin`.

XPath Solution:

```
//a[contains(@href, '/siteadmin') and @title='Websites']
```

Css Selector Solution:

```
a[href*='/siteadmin'][title='Websites']
```